# Lazy Initialization in NHibernate

Tags: .net, linq, nhibernate, lazy-initialization

If an entity is mapped with a relation to another entity as Lazy=False, but for a certain function I need to fetch them all Lazily, is that possible to do at run-time?

Comment: It is much easier to do the opposite...

Comment: Are you sure "Lazy" is what you want? Personally, I've _never_ needed to disable it. In practice, you'll more likely use `fetch="join"` to automatically retrieve specific associations. And *that* can be controlled in criteria queries and QueryOver using `SetFetchMode(...,  FetchMode.Lazy)` (criteria) or `Fetch(...).Lazy` (QueryOver). BTW, +1 on defaulting to lazy behavior. You can *enable* join-fetching in all APIs, but AFAIK can't explicitly disable it in LINQ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't. As commenters pointed out, you can map it as lazy and fetch eagerly, but not the other way round.

I.e. in LINQ you can fetch relationship eagerly with `Fetch`/`FetchMany`/`ThenFetch`/`ThenFetchMany`:

```
session.Query<Parent>()
    .Where(x => x.Name == "Ruba")
    .FetchMany(x => x.Children)
    .ThenFetch(x => x.SomethingMore);
```